# ImportError: cannot import name libsvm on importing svm

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, libsvm

I am facing an error when I am trying to import svm:

```
from sklearn import svm
```

**Error**:

```
ImportError: cannot import name libsvm
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling sklearn, but the error still persists. My current version of sklearn is scikit-learn-0.20.1
Version of ubuntu: 16.04

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: are you using anaconda for python package manager?

Comment: Nope. Not using anaconda.

Comment: Then try: `sudo apt-get install python-libsvm `

Comment: Tried. The error still persists.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new.py", line 6, in <module>
    from sklearn import svm
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/svm/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .classes import SVC, NuSVC, SVR, NuSVR, OneClassSVM, LinearSVC, \
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/svm/classes.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .base import _fit_liblinear, BaseSVC, BaseLibSVM
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import libsvm, liblinear
ImportError: cannot import name libsvm

Comment: I see, looks like sklearn is bundled with libsvm. how did you install sklearn?

Comment: sudo pip install scikit-learn

Comment: check the installation dependencies for linux [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/advanced_installation.html#linux), then reinstall sklearn.

Comment: Followed up on the link, installed the dependencies ad then reinstalled sklearn. Error still persists.

Comment: Are you using python 2 or 3?

Comment: I am using python2